# STM Prescaler - what happens if it's negative or too big?

Tags: pwm, stm32, timer

I'm using an STM32

The osciloscope is showing really weird stuff and resetting all PWM parameters on STM doesn't help (for another board readings are okay).

What happens if I set timer prescaler (using __HAL_TIM_SET_PRESCALER) to some incorrect value, like negative number or too big one? Can it screw something up?

Comment: If you are talking about causing a hardware damage then no, it can't.

Comment: Use the Cube mx software or the spreadsheet for you device to set the clock system correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ST timer prescalers are **unsigned 16 bit numbers**.
You cannot represent a negative nunmber in an unsigned 16 bit register.

Set your Windows calculator to Progammer made, select Word size, and enter -1.
The result is 0xFFFF, maximum prescaler. Due to the [two's complement signing method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

You also can't fit a number larger than 65535. You can try to write 0xFFFF'FFFF,
but the high halfword (16 bit) will be discarded.